# how to get SE value from R coxph

Tags: r

I'm trying to extract the SE value from a coxph object, expanding from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/324042/get-standard-error-of-exponentiated-coefficient-in-cox-regression:

```
library(survival)
library(survey)

res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
```

which shows a nice coxph object:

```
> res.cox
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

       coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z       p
sex -0.5310    0.5880   0.1672 -3.176 0.00149

Likelihood ratio test=10.63  on 1 df, p=0.001111
n= 228, number of events= 165
```

However, I need a way to extract the `se(coef)` value, and I don't know how to do that through `res.cox`, and such an extraction may not be possible, so I use `survey`:

```
s <- svycontrast(res.cox, quote(exp(sex)))
```

which looks like

```
> s
         nlcon     SE
contrast 0.588 0.0983
```

but the `SE` value is wrong!

How can I get the `se(coef)` value from `res.cox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `summary` on a coxph object, you get a list-like object that contains several members, including the `coefficients` table. You can pluck out the `se(coef)` column with standard indexing, so in your example you could get at the `se` with:

```r
summary(res.cox)$coefficients[,"se(coef)"]
#> [1] 0.1671786
```

Comment: thank you! Is there a way that I could specify the input variable, `sex` in this?

Comment: @con yes, you can do `summary(res.cox)$coefficients["sex", "se(coef)"]`